# DSL with Groovy -> passing parameter values

Tags: groovy, dsl

I'm new to Groovy and I'm trying to write a mini DSL for some specific task. 
For this purpose I've been trying to solve a problem like this below: 
I'd like to print (and/or return) 5 by calling this code (without using parantheses):

```
give me 5
```

I expected that a definition like this below would work:

```
def give = {clos ->  return clos} 
def me = {clos ->  println clos; return clos}
```

but actually it doesn't. Could you please help me how to define "give" and "me" in order to return the value 5 with the expression "give me 5"  where *me* must be a closure, *give* could be also metaClass, property etc.

Thanks in advance! 
Iv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groovy 1.8+ takes

```
give me 5
```

and the parser effectively tries to do:

```
give( me ).5
```

So, if you write your code like this, it works:

```
def give = { map ->  map } 
def me = [:].withDefault { it }

a = give me 5

println a
```

prints:

```
5
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. 
Could you reference some place where I can read more about the [:].withDefault construction?

Comment: @ivita No worries! It's defined [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#withDefault%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).  One thing to be aware of is that the `'5'` it is printing out is actually a String, and not an `Integer`.  This is because it tries to get `5` as a property name (String), so returns a String as well

Comment: I need it as string :-) Thanks!

Comment: @tim Perhaps you should note your answer only works in Groovy 1.8 and later.

Comment: @tim I did my rules in the way you suggested, now the problem is how to add more metaclass methods on the right. E.g.

Comment: @tim continues... 
`give me 5 like romanLetter -> V   OR
give me 5 like word -> five`

my intuition is that I define *like* as 

`Object.metaClass.like = {orth ->
     if (orth.equals("roman")){
        println "V"}
     else {println "five"}
    }`this metaClass method *like* works only if there is a returned value from the left to be applied to, right? I tried adding a return statement in all of the closures which are on the left side but I always receive `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: like for class: com.ontotext.paces.rules.FERulesScriptTest`
... how shall I do?

Comment: @tim_yates this is only a reference to your nickname to make sure you get my comment. thanks in advance!

Comment: This is where you need to have a think about all the possible forms you want to return.  It's probably going to be best to switch to a builder style as things get more complicated, as the code above isn't going to cut it without being quite hacky...  Also, this seems almost a new question? :-/

Answer (score 1):

Your closures are correct. Braces are missing. Try this

```
give(me(5)) or 
give me(5)
```

Else if you completely need to eliminate braces, assign the portions to a variable so as to let the parser understand what exactly needs to be passed.

```
five = me 5
give five
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I forgot to mention that I want my rules to work without parentheses. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

What is your method meant to do? You've written a syntactic requirement:

```
give me 5
```

If the *me* could be *you*, you'd need:

```
give("me", 5)
give "me", 5 //equivalent "DSL" notation
give("you", 7)
give "you", 7 //equivalent "DSL" notation

//or...
def me= "Mickey", you= "Donald"
give(me, 5)
give me, 5 //equivalent "DSL" notation
give(you, 7)
give you, 7 //equivalent "DSL" notation
```

If the *me* never changes, the semantics is closest to:

```
giveMe(5)
giveMe 5 //equivalent "DSL" notation
```

You've written "*me* must be a closure" and "I want my rules to work without parentheses", starting from syntactic constraints. Always start from semantic requirements :-)